# Padding short sequences with GAPs using Biopython

Tags: python, padding, fill

I would like my sequences to have the same length and, hence, fill with GAPs ( - ) the shorter ones depending on on the longest of my fasta file. In brief, I thought that the best way to achieve it was to find the longest sequence and then add GAPs to the others but probably there is a faster option. Note that I do not want to use an alignment function but just **fill** the sorther sequences. Here below the script that I wanted (unsuccessfully since it is not working) to run

```
max_length=0

for sequence in SeqIO.parse(path/to/file, 'fasta'):
         length=len(sequence.seq)
         if length > max_length:
                  max_length= length
         else:
                 pass

for sequence in SeqIO.parse(path/to/file, 'fasta'):
     length=len(sequence.seq)
     if length < max_length:
              sequence.seq=sequence.seq+Seq('-')
              if len(sequence.seq) == max_length:
                          break
              else:
                          continue

SeqIO.write(sequence, path/to/new/file, 'fasta')
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seq object have an API a bit similar to strings, (but are lacking useful stuff like `ljust` in that case).
Here is a possible solution :

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

sequences = [s for s in SeqIO.parse('seq.fasta', 'fasta')]
max_len = max([len(s.seq) for s in sequences])
GAPs = "-"
for seq in sequences:
    padding = GAPs*(max_len - len(seq.seq)) # creating the padding string
    seq.seq += padding

SeqIO.write(sequences, 'newseq.fasta', 'fasta')
```

This solution is not really optimized because, as in your attempt, we look first for the maximum length, and then we pad. To pad, this solution uses two useful operators on strings:

- `*`, that repeat a string a certain number of time, to get a padding of the desired length.
- `+` to concatenate two strings

We find the maximum length using a list comprehension and the builtin max function.